# Parsing Listbox results and updating values

Tags: parsing, vba, ms-access, listbox

The included code pulls parameters from a form and executes a stored procedure. The result is captured via a list box object and  displayed on the form. How can I parse the result from the stored procedure, modify values, and then submit it back so the list box shows the updates?

My stored procedure returns a list of user accounts and their status (1,0). What I want to do is update the status from 1,0 to true,false so that when the results are shown in the form, the listbox shows true and false as opposed to 1,0.

```
Dim paramAcctNo As String
Dim paramProfileId As String
Dim query1 As String
Dim query2 As String

'Populating the form parameters
paramAcctNo = [Forms]![frm_userlookup]![lst_searchresults]
paramProfileId = [Forms]![frm_userlookup]![tb_hidden]

'Executing SP
query1 = "EXEC dbo.sp_ADCON_userDetailView '" & paramAcctNo & "','" & paramProfileId & "'"

'assigning results to listbox to display in form
Me.listbox1.RowSource = query1
```

Comment: I'm not sure of the full intent of your question, but in Excel if you want to replace all the 1s and 0s in your string, you can use `query1 = Replace(query1, "1", "true")` and then `query1 = Replace(query1, "0", "false")`

Comment: Thanks for the response. i'm not using Excel..not sure if it matters. This is for an Access based form with a SQL Server backend. If i do the replace command, will it replace all input whereever a 1 is listed with a "true". My out put is a table, which is why i was wanting to parse it and just update the column with the status. i will give this a try.

Comment: just tried the Replace query and it didn't work. doesn't error out, but my query doesn't give me an output either

Comment: I misunderstood what you were doing.  The `Replace` code was meant to operate on a string of 1s and 0s, not an Access table, or query result.

Comment: thanks! query 1 is more just just strings of 1s and 0s. sorry should have clarified. it includes the userid, description, status, etc. one of the data elements is status. what i'm trying to do is isolate the status bit, update it and reinsert it back into my resultset. i'm thinking this will be done easily when i'm dealing with a listbox as opposed to a string.

Answer (score 1):

If you are allowed to change the actual values in the `query1` table after your stored procedure has run, you can run two simple `UPDATE` queries to change the 1s to True and the 0s to False.

```
UPDATE query1 SET [field name that contains the 1] = "True"
WHERE ([field name that contains the 1]="1")

UPDATE query1 SET [field name that contains the 0] = "False"
WHERE ([field name that contains the 0]="0")
```

A problem that you might run into is with a Type mismatch error.  If the field containing the 0s and 1s is numeric, you won't be able to update it to a string value.

Comment: thanks! appreciate the quick response. i will give this a shot.